# How do I install Autotest and Autotest Pure on Windows/Cygwin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't find any instructions on how a Windows user is supposed to do this, so how would I do this for Rails with Cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this, but are you certain it won't work just off the get go? I know it depends on the native notification system, but Windows does have one already. Try to just install the autotest gems and run autotest in Cygwin:

```
gem install autotest-notification
gem install autotest-rails
an-install
```

Then run `autotest` and see what happens. It probably won't know about the Windows notification, but you should still be able to have it automatically test things as you go along, and still be able to see the offending tests if something goes wrong.